# I'd like to edit the window style for gVim is that possible?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, themes, gvim

I'd like to change the way gnome styles the window for gVim specifically (maybe firefox in the future) I want to remove the thin white/off white border, and possible recolor the title bar area to match my gVim background.

Any help would rock!

I'm on Gnome Ubuntu (just upgraded Ubuntu to 14.04) with Gnome 3.9.90. I'm using the default theme Adwaita.

Answer (score 2):

Well the only way I know of is to edit the themes on gnome.  The easiest way to do that is install `gnome-tweak-tool` in apt, then install elegance theme editor (this allows you to completely modify the shell color)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:satyajit-happy/themes
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-theme-elegance-colors
```

to use this you will have to install user themes gnome extension. You will be propted with the install link upon making any changes in elegance.

Next would be to either google gnome themes maybe use the theme name that you are using in vim.  Or look at gnome-look.org.

Also in your `~/.vimrc` file you can make changes to gVim.  I prefer to remove the side scrollbars and the icon menu

```
set guioptions-=T  "remove toolbar
set guioptions-=r  "remove right-hand scroll bar
set guioptions-=L  "remove left-hand scroll bar
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I have an updated version of the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900779/how-can-i-change-the-title-bar-of-a-gnome-theme-to-black